# No. of errors possible

Tags: programming-languages

Is it possible to get 21 errors for a 20 line program in Any language? Any platform. ? Sorry if this should not be asked. I m new to programming. My trainer asked me this question. Can someone help or explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is; you can certainly have multiple errors on a line.

Comment: Yes - you could write 20 lines of code that won't compile and have one of those create a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

C++:

```
trolo = lolo;  //1 line
```

Errors:

```
error C2065: 'trolo' : undeclared identifier

error C2065: 'lolo' : undeclared identifier
```

C#:

```
al; cas; r; sb; ds; es; ew; qw; 2; 32; a; int a = 2.3;
```

1 line, **exactly 21 errors**.:D